# On operations upon limits of functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Having read chapter 1.7 from Courant’s “Course in Differential and Integral Calculus”, the following question has arisen: at the very end of the chapter, the author provides the following example $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 - 1} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}{1 - \frac{1}{x^2}} $$ Is the latter passage really correct? For if we divide both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, we have to include the fact that 0 is to be left out of the domain of the initial function. Are we really making a rigorous statement whilst changing the domain?

Comment: It helps to write down the expression in terms of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we are. Since we are dealing with the limit at $\infty$, it follows from the definition of this limit that all that we need is to have an equality which is valid on some interval $(M,\infty)$, for some real number $M$. And the equality$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{1+\frac1{x^2}}$$holds on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Excuse me for asking a really stupid question, but how does it follow from the definition of the limit at infinity that the equality must hold on the mentioned interval $(M,\infty)$?

Comment: By definition, if $L$ is a real number and $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is a function, then the assertion $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists R\in\Bbb R):x>R\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: So, if you consider a real function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x$ belongs to the domain of $g$ and such that this domain contains an interval $(M,\infty)$, then, if you prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=L$, this means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists R\in\Bbb R):x>R\implies\bigl|g(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon$$and then, if $x>\max\{R,M\}$, you also have $\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Barbatulka: here is something to ponder. Replace $x$ by $x-10^{100}$ in your function. Then a similar division creates problem at $x=10^{100}$ but that's no big deal when $x\to\infty $. Just ignore the values of $x$ which are less than or equal to $10^{100}$. Symbolically, when dealing with $x\to\infty $ the values of $x<M$ for any specified $M$ don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $0$ makes no sense in the rewritten expression has no effect on the limit at infinity.